# What is a more formal complexity of O(n/2)?

Tags: big-o

I need to know how to analyze algorithms from the perspective of a discrete math class. This is not homework, the example is from [here at 1:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TlHvipP5yA&list=PLDN4rrl48XKpZkf03iYFl-O29szjTrs_O&index=6). Meaning, I need to to know the constants, not just the general big-0. This is the method or algorithm I'm confused with. Would It not be `3n/2 + 1`.

My thought is that for the first method the for loop runs `n(1/2) + 1` times and inside the for loop the statement is run n times, or maybe `O(1/2)` times inside as well. Then, add these two.

For the subsequent method, the loop executes `n + 1` times and `n` inside. So I believe it would be `(n + 1) + n`. So, `2n + 1`. This is the process I'm following for the first method but I'm not quite as confident.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i = i+2) { // n(1/2) + 1
    do something; //n
}

for(i = 0; i < n; i = i++) { // n + 1
    do something; //n
}
```

Comment: Big-O notation is only a *generalization* for the type of growth a function will have.  For example, `n^2` and `n^3` are both considered `O(n^2)` since those functions have similar-looking growth graphs.  Therefore, in your example, the function `3n/2 + 1` would be considered `O(n)`.

Comment: This is correct, I'm aware it is `O(n)`. I might not have been clear enough. I'm wondering what the constants are. Like for the second method, If I did that one correctly it is `2n + 1` or 1O(n)`. I'm having trouble finding the constants for the first method by analyzing and adding the operations.

Comment: For your first loop, it starts at 0 and grows in increments of 2, so its function would be `2n`.  Your second function starts at 0 and grows in increments of 1, so its function would be `n`.

Comment: When trying to find the function for something like this, the starting value and rate of growth will be how you determine its Big-O notation.

Comment: @Tau "`n^2` and `n^3` are both considered `O(n^2)`" That is not true. `n^3 <= k*n^2` will always be false for large enough `n`, no matter which `k` you pick. Specifically it will be false once `n > k`. So `n^3` is *not* in `O(n^2)`. Consequently `O(n^3)` is a strict superset of `O(n^2)`.